# New Ganache (1.1.0-beta.0) Causes Invalid JSON RPC response

Tags: truffle, testing, error, mocha

Hey I'm running a test where I expect a transaction to throw. Instead of successfully returning a receipt with a status of 0, or throwing a `revert` error, it throws this invalid JSON RPC response error.

Example:

```
try {
    // some generic transaction with a contract that should fail via revert or require.
    await promise;
} catch (error) {
    const revertEvent = error.message.search('revert') >= 0;
    assert(revertEvent, 'expected revert');
}
```

and I get the stacktrace:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":202,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:41483:16)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:330353:36
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:326008:9
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329052:7)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176427:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176717:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176872:12)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176832:24)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:198:9)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maintainer of ganache here. This is a known bug in the beta. See https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/471